# count '9's from 1 to n python optimization

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
def count_nines(n):
    x = list(map(str,range(n + 1)))
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        c = i.count('9')
        count += c 
    return count
```

Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)

How can i optimize this code ?

Comment: you are first casting the range into a list of strings. Don't do that. Make a normal `for i in range(n):`  and then cast this `i` to a string.  Then you might want to take another approach.  How would you as a human check how many nines are between 1 and 99? Do you really need to check 11, then 12, then 13...? Or can you think something more optimal?

Comment: Or at least iterate over `map` object (`for i in map(str,range(n + 1))`) so you don't generate a big list of strings but do it one value at a time.

Comment: You could probably optimize it by using that fact that count_nine(10**k) = k*10**(k-1), then using the decimal decomposition of n.

Comment: You don't optimise *this* code. You write completely new, unrelated code, based on completely different principles.

Comment: First thing for optimizing is always measuring the performance, so you define a few benchmarks that you want to optimize. Then, you use a profiler to find out where each part of the code spends its time, so you form an idea which would be most advantageous to optimize.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Then realize that your algorithmic complexity is way too high to ever have a slightest hope of passing the test, scrap the code, and start over. Which you could have done without ever knowing what a profiler is, or running a single benchmark.

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm is clearly linear, which is often good enough, but not here for the huge target number(s).

Answer (score 4):

Here's some working code (I tested it on some not too big numbers, and it returns the same results as yours) based on my comment:

```
def count_nines(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    k = len(str(n))-1
    leading_digit, remainder = divmod(n, 10**k)  # Thanks @Stef for this optimization
    # Number of nines in numbers from 1 to leading_digit * 10**k - 1
    count1 = leading_digit * k*10**(k-1)
    # If the leading_digit is 9, number of times it appears
    # (in numbers from  9 * 10**k to n)
    count2 = remainder+1 if leading_digit==9 else 0
    # Number of nines in remainder
    count3 = count_nines(remainder)
    # Total number of nines
    return int(count1 + count2 + count3)
```

**Explanations**

- For starters, the numbers of nines (shortened as c9() hereafter) in 1-10^k is k * 10^(k-1); this is easy to prove by recurrence, but I'll just explain on an example:
  assuming c9(1000) = 300, the number of nines in the xxx part of numbers 0xxx, 1xxx ... 9xxx is equal to 10 * 300; add to that the number of **9** in **9**xxx is 1000 (from **9**000 to **9**999), which yields c9(10000) = 10*300 + 1000 = 4000 .
- Now imagine you want c9(7935) : you have 7 * 300 nines in numbers 1-7000, then 9*20 nines in numbers 7 000 to 7 900, then 36 **leading nines** in number **9**00 to **9**35, then ...

**Example**

```
count_nines(9254287593789050756)
Out[12]: 16880680640899572416
```

Comment: In the spirit of clear code I would also replace `return int(leading_digit*k*10**(k-1) + (remainder+1 if leading_digit==9 else 0) + count_nines(remainder))` with `self_explaining_name1 = leading_digit*k*10**(k-1); self_explaining_name2 = remainder+1 if leading_digit==9 else 0; self_explaining_name3 = count_nines(remainder); return self_explaining_name1 + self_explaining_name2 + self_explaining_name3`

Comment: Also I don't understand why there is a call to `int( ... )` on the return line, aren't those already int?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it returned a float (and I confess I didn't investigate); perhaps with the use of divmod it isn't needed anymore. I'll test that (and I'll think about segmenting the calculation like you suggested). Edit: tested; it returns xxx.0 without `int`.